Pixelated render for beginners help
New here, I used Cycles to render my Video - and now I'm stuck.
It has created a very pixelated image.


Hi Wurd, welcome to BSE. We like to help...but...we need some minimum information what you did. One picture isn't enough for that. Since it looks like you are a beginner, please provide blend file so we can check it out on our own. thx.

Is this in the image editor, or the 3-D viewport? If the latter, what happens when you move about?

Please provide some details of your output settings, or better yet, share on https://blend-exchange.com/ , packing any relevant images into the file.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
